# Form add email address from Option Value

Tags: php, forms

I asked this question earlier but felt it was a little lengthy and not to the point. I am looking to add a contact to the `$to =` when one select `<option value="foo"`is selected out of the list of 5. I have little experience in PHP and this is a preexisting form on the site. The examples I have been looking at describe adding an array for multiple email addresses. However, I only need to add one email on one of the `<option value="foo"` not all 5 of the options. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Code is below thank you.

```
    <?
ob_start();

if(isset($_POST['registersubmit']))
{
    unset($badcaptcha);
    require_once('/recaptchalib.php');   
    $privatekey = "...";    
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);   
    if (!$resp->is_valid)
    {
        $badcaptcha=true;
    }
    else
    {
//Send email
//foo@test.com
    $to = "foo@test.com\r\n";
    $from = "test.com <contact@test.com>";
    $subject = "Parts Inquiry test\r\n";
    $body = "Parts Inquiry test\r\n\n";

    //$body .= "Know The Part Number: ".$_POST['ToggleDivs']."\r\n\n";

    if($_POST['ToggleDivs']=="yes")
    { 
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty1']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts1']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty2']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts2']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty3']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts3']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty4']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts4']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty5']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts5']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty6']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts6']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty7']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts7']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty8']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts8']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty9']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts9']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Qty: ".$_POST['qty10']." Parts Number: ".$_POST['parts10']."\r\n\n";  
    } 
    else
    {
    $body .= "Make: ".$_POST['Make']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Model: ".$_POST['model']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "VIN: ".$_POST['vin']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Category: \r\n\n";
    $body .= "*".$_POST['category1']."*".$_POST['category2']."*".$_POST['category3']."*".$_POST['category4']."*".$_POST['category5']."*".$_POST['category6']."*".$_POST['category7']."*".$_POST['category8']."*".$_POST['category9']."*".$_POST['category10']."*".$_POST['category11']."*".$_POST['category12']."*".$_POST['category13']."*".$_POST['category14']."*".$_POST['category15']."*".$_POST['category16']."*".$_POST['category17']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Describe the part(s) you need: \r\n\n";
    $body .= "".$_POST['parts_info']."\r\n\n";
    }

    $body .= "\r\n\n";
    $body .= "##############################\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Do you have an account with us? ".$_POST['acct']."\r\n\n";
    if($_POST['acct']=="yes")
    { 
    $body .= "My account number is: ".$_POST['acct_n']."\r\n\n";
    /*$body .= "Do you have an account with us? ".$_POST['acct']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "If yes, this is the account number: ".$_POST['acct_n']."\r\n\n";*/
    }
    if($_POST['ship_opts']=="Delivery")
    {
        $body .= "Shipping option: ".$_POST['ship_opts']." \r\n\n";
    }
    else if($_POST['ship_opts']=="Other")
    {
        $body .= "Other shipping option selected: ".$_POST['ship_other']."\r\n\n";
    }
    else 
    {
    $body .= "Will Pick Up at: ".$_POST['ship_opts']." \r\n\n";
    $body .= "This is the pick up date: ".$_POST['pick_up_date']."\r\n\n";
    //$body .= "Other shipping option selected: ".$_POST['ship_other']."\r\n\n";
    }
    $body .= "\r\n\n";
    $body .= "##############################\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Contact's Information:\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Full Name: ".$_POST['Fname']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Business Name: ".$_POST['Bname']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Address: ".$_POST['address']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "City: ".$_POST['city']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "State: ".$_POST['state']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Zip Code: ".$_POST['zipcode']."\r\n\n";   
    $body .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Location: ".$_POST['location']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Comments/Message: ".$_POST['details']."\r\n\n";   

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);

//Send copy  omega@test.com
$to = "omega@test.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);

    $to = "alpha@test.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);

   $to = "beta@test.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);



if ($_POST['ship_opts'] == 'foo') {
    $to = "foo@test.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);
}




    header("Location:thankyou_contact2.php");
    }
}

$linkname="parts1";
if(empty($id)) { $id = 23; $showplus = "Y"; }
include("includes/header.php");
?>
```

HTML below;

```
<div id="pick_up" style="display: none;position:relative;">
<label style="clear:both;"> Do you plan to pick up at one of our locations or have it delivered?<br />
  <select name="ship_opts" id="ship_opts" onchange="Toggle3(this.value);">
    <option value="">Make a Selection</option>
    <option value="PU_C">Pick-Up C</option>
    <option value="PU_D">Pick-Up D</option>
    <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    </select> 
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Don't use php short tags `<?` - use the full opening tag: `<?php` - 2) Why the ob_start() - unless you're doing some sort of output buffering, not necessary.  - 3) You just need an if statement, but I can't see the select list you are mentioning where the `<option value="foo">` lives, so I don't know what variable(s) to check / construct the if statement around.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up this is a pre-existing form they just want this minor update. I will updated the short tags and use the full opening. I added in the HTML for the select menu. The email address can be foo@test.com. @cale_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have this code:

```
$to = "foo@test.com\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);
```

Simply change it to read:

```
if ($_POST['ship_opts'] == 'foo') {
    $to = "foo@test.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);
}
```

And then it will only send the copy if the 'foo' option is selected.

If you want **every** email to get copied to the foo@test.com address, then alter your headers to include either a Cc or Bcc:

```
if ($_POST['ship_opts'] == 'foo') {
    $headers.= "Cc: foo@test.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Cale. I need the form to send when any option is selected. But, when the Foo option is selected the value adds another email address to the preexisting send to's.

Comment: @ac12 - that's what the above will do.  If it's not what you want, please specify the difference exactly, because the code above sends the email always, but **only** sends a copy to foo if the selected option is "foo"

Comment: Thank you Cale. I edited the above code in my first post. I was misreading your answer at first I apologize. I was reading that it would only send if that option was selected but wouldn't send if else.

Comment: Does the edited code above look correct to you? Thanks so much for taking the time to help.